# Launching an app using its URL on OpenShift Origin

Tags: dns, paas, openshift-origin

I'm learning to use the open source version of OpenShift. I have downloaded the linux image and started it on a virtual machine (named VM1) on my PC, which runs Windows 7. On another VM (named VM2) I have installed another linux OS and configured the JBoss IDE to work with OpenShift. Then I have successfully created and hosted an app on my local OpenShift PaaS cloud. Here is where the problem starts:

On VM2 (the one running linux where I developed the app) I have no problem accessing my account webpage on OpenShift, viewing what apps I have created and testing them.

From any other PC on my network I can log in to the OpenShift web console and view my apps by simply entering the IP of VM1 (in my case 192.168.1.107). There I can see the URL to launch my app: http://localtest2-mydomain.openshift.local/ . But when I click on it, I get a message saying that the web page is not available. Again, if I use this link in VM2, it works like a charm.

I tried changing the system32\drivers\etc\hosts file so that and link ending in openshift.local will be sent to the IP address of VM1, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not use wildcards in your hosts file, you would need to specify the entire url in your hosts file for it to find it correctly.  Give that a try and see if it helps.